# Aurman asking for root privilege to install from AUR

Tags: package-management, antergos, aur

I'm using Antergos. While installing an AUR package with aurman, it requires password. Why does it need root access to install package as by git clone and 'makepkg -si' I can install it with root privilege?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because aurman is just a pacman wrapper: so it is using `-U, --upgrade` to install the [built packages from the AUR](https://github.com/polygamma/aurman/blob/master/src/aurman/classes.py#L1178):

> -U, --upgrade
>              Upgrade or add package(s) to the system and install the required dependencies from sync repositories

This operation requires elevated privileges.